# How to move multiple shapes in a swing GUI by a specified amount

Tags: java, swing

I have created a GUI in Java and in the main JPanel I have created 1000 ovals and a big circle. Now, I want that when I press the START button, all these shapes should move by 5 places in x.

How should I approach this problem. How will I get the current coordinates of the shapes and add a distance(for example: 5) in that?

MainPanel

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    Algorithm pf = new Algorithm(); 

    public MainPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680,450));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("START"))
        {
                pf.particleFilter();
                repaint();
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {   
        super.paintComponent(g);
        pf.initializePanel(g); 
    }

}
```

Initialize Code

```
public class Algorithm {

    int robot_x=0;
    int robot_y=0;     
    int robot_radius=50;
    int counter=0;

    public void particleFilter()
    {
        move();
    }   

    public void move()
    {

    }

    public void initializePanel(Graphics g)
    {
        drawNParticles(g);
        createRobot(g); 
        createObstacle(g,150,225,100,40);
        createObstacle(g,500,300,40,100);  
    }

    private void createRobot(Graphics g)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> robot_list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        robot_list=positionRobot(robot_x,robot_y);
        robot_x=robot_list.get(0);
        robot_y=robot_list.get(1);
        drawRobot(g,robot_x,robot_y,robot_radius);
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> positionRobot(int x, int y)
    {
        int robot_radius=50;   
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x=randomInteger(25,655);//so that it stays inside the content_Walls panel 
        y=randomInteger(25,425); //so that it stays inside the content_Walls panel 
        x=x-(robot_radius/2);
        y=y-(robot_radius/2);
        if((x<251&&x>149)&&(y<266&&y>224))
        {
           x=0;
           y=0;
           positionRobot(x,y);
        }
        else if((x<=541&&x>499)&&(y<401&&y>299))
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            positionRobot(x,y);
        }
            list.add(x);
            list.add(y);    
            return list;                
    }

    private void drawNParticles(Graphics g)
    {
        int n=1000; // n denotes the number of particles    
        ArrayList<Integer> list;        
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(n, 0));
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
           generateParticle(g);
        }
    }

    private void generateParticle(Graphics g)
    {
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        int radius = 4;
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list=positionParticles(x,y);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(list.get(0),list.get(1), radius, radius);
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> positionParticles(int x, int y)
    {
        int radius = 4;
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x=randomInteger(2,678); // bounds of x between which the particles should be generated
        y=randomInteger(2,448); // bounds of y between which the particles should be generated
        x=x-(radius/2);
        y=y-(radius/2);
        if((x<251&&x>149)&&(y<266&&y>224))
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            positionParticles(x,y);
        }
        if((x<541&&x>499)&&(y<401&&y>299))
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            positionParticles(x,y);
        }
        list.add(x);
        list.add(y);
        return list;
    }



    private void createObstacle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void drawRobot(Graphics g, int x, int y, int radius)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);   
    }

    private static Random rand;
    private static int randomInteger(int min, int max)
    {
        if(rand==null)
            rand=new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

}
```

Right now, it just places them randomly again. I have tried repaint, but I was not able to do this. Any ideas how it should be done?

Comment: logics could be reverse to create an array and inside paintComponent only to loop inside this array

Comment: @mKorbel Can you pleas elaborate it a little more?

Comment: Your shapes could be their own class with each instance having its own x and y values. Then you keep a list of the ones you want drawn. Then, when you paint you just iterate the list, add 5 to each shapes x coordinate, then draw it.

Comment: fill array before code line repaint() in ActionListener is executed, move pf.initializePanel(g); before repaint()

Comment: @Takendarkk do you mean i should use an arraylist to store the locations of the shapes and then increment those values by 5?

Comment: @Takendarkk because it will hog a lot of memory and I plan to increase the shapes to 5k in future.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. Maybe you should ask the question, why would I ever need to draw 5000 shapes at one time? Maybe there is a better way.